# How to load a page fragment via Ajax with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here's my script for loading a certain page via ajax.

```
$(function(){

      // Keep a mapping of url-to-container for caching purposes.
      var cache = {
        // If url is '' (no fragment), display this div's content.
        '': $('.bbq-default')
      };

      // Bind an event to window.onhashchange that, when the history state changes,
      // gets the url from the hash and displays either our cached content or fetches
      // new content to be displayed.
      $(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) {

        // Get the hash (fragment) as a string, with any leading # removed. Note that
        // in jQuery 1.4, you should use e.fragment instead of $.param.fragment().
        var url = $.param.fragment();

        // Remove .bbq-current class from any previously "current" link(s).
        $( 'a.bbq-current' ).removeClass( 'bbq-current' );

        // Hide any visible ajax content.
        $( '.bbq-content' ).children( ':visible' ).hide();

        // Add .bbq-current class to "current" nav link(s), only if url isn't empty.
        url && $( 'a[href="#' + url + '"]' ).addClass( 'bbq-current' );

        if ( cache[ url ] ) {
          // Since the element is already in the cache, it doesn't need to be
          // created, so instead of creating it again, let's just show it!
          cache[ url ].show();
        } else {
          // Show "loading" content while AJAX content loads.
          $( '.bbq-loading' ).show();

          // Create container for this url's content and store a reference to it in
          // the cache.

          cache[ url ] = $( '<div class="bbq-item"/>' )


            // Append the content container to the parent container.
            .appendTo( '.bbq-content' )


            // Load external content via AJAX. Note that in order to keep this
            // example streamlined, only the content in .infobox is shown. You'll
            // want to change this based on your needs.
            .load( url, function(){
              // Content loaded, hide "loading" content.
              $( '.bbq-loading' ).hide();
            });
        }
      })
      // Since the event is only triggered when the hash changes, we need to trigger
      // the event now, to handle the hash the page may have loaded with.
      $(window).trigger( 'hashchange' );
    });
```

I am usng the JQuery BBQ plugin, now my question how can I get the only the div of the page that  I want to load? not the whole page itself, any idea how?

Comment: You can't load only one div, but you can `find` it in returned data.

Comment: @eicto  actually you can and is part of the `load` method

Comment: @charlietfl it is search through the page after loading....

Comment: @eicto yes...full page is retrieved, but `load` will search for selector provided in argument without you manually calling `find`

Comment: I almost never use `load` method, so i answered using `load` therm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`load()` method allows for adding a selector after the actual file url to only load content that matches the selector.

For example:

```
$('#someDiv').load('myFile.php #contentDiv');/* note space before selector*/
```

This will retrive the full output of `myFile.php` but only insert `contentDiv` from that output into `somediv`

If selector is a class with multiple items it will retrieve them all

API reference: http://api.jquery.com/load/

See section titled `Load Fragments`